# Return System Notification When Long-running Comint Process Completes?

Tags: ess, process, comint, notifications

I often have long-running processes in comint shells (e.g. SQL or fitting statistical models, both usually via an R/ESS shell).

While they're running I navigate away and do something in another buffer, and try to remember to check-back periodically. I often check-back too soon, and then get distracted.

It would be ideal if I could write a function to trigger an informative system notification using notifications.el, whenever a process left running in a comint buffer completed (for any process, which, say, had already taken longer than 90 seconds).

How could I write such a function, to produce a system-notification such-as "A process in [buffer-name] has completed."?

Comment: I have a `ready` function that I call after such long-running command (simply running it after the previous one so will be triggered once the other command finished), which sends e-mail or a notification to my mobile via Pushbullet or simply calls`notify-send` to trigger a system notification on Linux. This approach works well both on localhost and remote ESS sessions, but requires you to manually enter/call `ready()` whenever you want to be notified.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've used exactly this system with push-bullet before. However, I'm pretty set on system notifications for this use-case.